# SSIS: Overwite the data source/server in a connection string read from a package configuration value

Tags: ssis

I have looked at other posts and questions but I couldn't find what I needed.

I am relatively new to SSIS Package creation so bear with me please.

Basically, I need the package to connect to multiple servers based on a list of IPs read from a table.  I have a connection string that I am reading from a config table.  the connection string is generic in that the datasource is simply 255.255.255.255 and I want to replace the datasource with the IPs read from the table as I loop through during package execution.

I am using IPs since the servers I am connecting to are not on our domain.  I have set up the server name as a variable within the connection manager expressions.  Thus what I am hoping is that the pkg config is read to obtain the entire connection string. Then as I loop through the IPs, the server name variable will be dynamically substituted into the data source value as it loops thorugh.  I hope this makes sense.

So the connstring is: (generic within config table)

```
Data Source=255.255.255.255,65000;User ID=test;Password=test;Initial Catalog=myDB;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;Application Name=SSIS-myApp;
```

Then as I obtain the list of IPs I want it to change to and then obviously connect as:

```
Data Source=1.1.1.1,1000;User ID=test;Password=test;Initial Catalog=myDB;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;Application Name=SSIS-myApp;
```

Then the next IP and connect as:

```
Data Source=2.2.2.2,1000;User ID=test;Password=test;Initial Catalog=myDB;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;Application Name=SSIS-myApp;
```

How can I do this using SSIS?

Comment: in your title, do you mean _Override_ or _Overwrite_?

Answer (score 2):

- Create a connection manager connection to a valid database.
- Right click on the newly created connection manager connection, select to `Properties` and copy the value for the connection string
- Create a string variable and paste the connection string in your clip board in the value for the newly created variable
- Add an `Execute SQL Task` with a statement similar to this:

  SELECT TOP 1
      'Data Source=' + [IPAddress] +
      ';User ID='+[Username] +
      ...
  FROM dbo.IPTable
- Pass the result set to the string variable you previously created
- Right click on your connection manager connection and click the ellipsis next to `Expressions`
- In the dialog that pops out, under Property, select ConnectionString and click the ellipsis next to the blank value for Expression.
- In the Expression Builder, add the variable name to the variable you created. Ex: `@[User::CreatedVariableName]`

And you're finished.  This a basic concept and you can tweak from there..